Error with grant application pages
I've been struggling for a month or so now with an error when viewing certain grant application pages (using the Grand Application Pages Extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/grant-application-pages), but I think this relates to core CiviCRM rather than the extension.
Error is thrown on public facing pages on WordPress:
Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string - string in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/d6/24/4c/d6244c46f741d0a95614f2886a1c2e9f44e810c3_0.file.Main.tpl.php:61 Stack trace: #0 public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_672deaf990ba15_67238194(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
Have tried a lot of approaches to fix, now have the latest version of CiviCRM and all extensions are updated. The issue still persists? There are custom fields on the application page, but only text fields as far as I know.
Any thoughts?

Welcome to SE! Check you have the latest versions of the extension and CiviCRM. The error relates to Smarty 4: there was a fix relating to that a few months ago which is included in release 2.1

Thanks, that's great. However I upgrade CiviCRM this morning and all plugins, thinking that would resolve the issue. I found the fix too.
I am now on version 2.1 of the plugin, but the issue persists.

Not sure if it is related but when trying to edit any grant application pages from within the grants dashboard I now get this error:
[error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "Unrecognized entity type: GrantModel"
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#11082
#message: "Unrecognized entity type: GrantModel"
#code: 0
#file: "wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/UF/Page/ProfileEditor.php"
#line: 207

@BenAtkinson have you cleared your Civi caches?

@Coleman as far as I know, yes. Following the instructions during the upgrade.

@BenAtkinson and can you confirm the CiviGrant extension is enabled?
